# Preview an email attachment

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I have a use case for writing an outlook add-in using the office.js api.

When the on-send command is triggered a check will be done on the email attachment and if it fulfills some condition, I would like to show a preview of the file.

I am able to do the on-send checking part by following the MS sample code and would like to know is there is a way to invoke the built in preview pane in outlook to display the attachment?

Thank you.

Comment: Currently the feature to invoke inbuilt preview pane is not supported. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT thank you for the quick reply, I take it that the only way for me to carry out what I require would be to use the outlook rest api and send the attachment to another service that can render the document in a taskpane?

Comment: are you using outlook desktop or OWA?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I will be using both desktop and OWA.

Comment: Yes, that should work for your scenario.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Correct me if my understanding is wrong, in compose view on the web, if I click on-send and I try to do something like _var i = Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments.length;_ it will fail because the attachment actually does not exist yet in the mailbox item?

Comment: Yes, _var i = Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments.length_ will fail for Compose mode.It will work only in read mode.